# Need help splitting an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Hi i am trying to split an array into 2 or more arrays. Here is what i am trying to do:

My array:

```
array(size=5)
  0=>
    array(size=3)
      'oid' => int 1
      payment_status => 'Paid'
      payment_type => 'Online'
  1=>
    array(size=3)
      'oid' => int 1
      payment_status => 'Paid'
      payment_type => 'Online'
  2=>
    array(size=3)
      'oid' => int 1
      payment_status => 'Paid'
      payment_type => 'Online'
  3=>
    array(size=3)
      'oid' => int 2
      payment_status => 'Paid'
      payment_type => 'Online'
  4=>
    array(size=3)
      'oid' => int 2
      payment_status => 'Paid'
      payment_type => 'Online'
```

I am trying to split this array like this:

```
array(size=3)
  0=>
    array(size=3)
      'oid' => int 1
      payment_status => 'Paid'
      payment_type => 'Online'
  1=>
    array(size=3)
      'oid' => int 1
      payment_status => 'Paid'
      payment_type => 'Online'
  2=>
    array(size=3)
      'oid' => int 1
      payment_status => 'Paid'
      payment_type => 'Online'
```

and

```
array(size=2)
  0=>
    array(size=3)
      'oid' => int 2
      payment_status => 'Paid'
      payment_type => 'Online'
  1=>
    array(size=3)
      'oid' => int 2
      payment_status => 'Paid'
      payment_type => 'Online'
```

So as you can see the array gets split into multiple arrays based on 'oid' value. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this output? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What's splitting logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple one, copy the items based on oid into a new array:

```
$input = $yourArray;

$output = array();

foreach($input as $item)
{
    $output[$item['oid']][] = $item;
}

var_dump($output);
```

output holds an array with oid as key.

you can access your separated array like this:

```
$output[1]; //for oid 1
$output[2]; //for oid 2
```

and so on

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to loop the output and print $output[1] results and $output[2] results separately. This is what i am doing 

foreach($output as $out)
foreach($out as $x)
     $x['payment_status']
endforeach
endforeach

But this prints 5 times, i just wanna print the result of first array and then the next one.

Comment: How do i print this using for loop ??

Comment: as you tried with the nested for loops. you have to add some spacer in the outer for loop. i.e. `foreach($output as $out){ foreach($out as $x){ print $x['payment_status']; } print "next array"; }`